# Multiple Embedded Collections

Tags: symfony

I have a PurchaseOrder Entity which has a OneToMany relation to an ArticleOrder Entity. Additionally the ArticleOrder Entity don't hold only the Order and Article ID , but also the Amount. Furthermore the ArticleOrder Entity has a OneToMany relation to another Entity named ArticleSupplier. So that the ordered Amount of every Article can be split to multiple Supplier. 
Now I want to build a form to solve this. So I created three Form Types:

One which holds only an embedded collection of the ArticleOrders:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('purchaseOrders', 'collection', array('type' => new ProducedAmountOrderArticleType()));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder',
    ));
}
```

One which holds an embedded collection of the ArticleSupplier entries:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('articleOrderReferences', 'collection', array('type' => new ProducedAmountOrderSubArticleType()));

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ArticleOrderReference',
    ));
}
```

And one for the ArticleSupplier Amount input field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('produced');

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\AOSupplierReference',
    ));
}
```

the twig code:

```
<span class="purchaseOrders">
                    {% for purchaseOrder in form.purchaseOrders %}
                        <span class="articleOrderReferences">
                            {% for articleOrderReference in form.articleOrderReferences %}
                                {{ form_errors(articleOrderReference.produced) }}
                                {{ form_widget(articleOrderReference.produced, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-mini'} }) }}
                            {% endfor %}<br>
                        </span>

                    {% endfor %}
                </span>
```

Controller:

```
           $form = $this->createForm(new ProducedAmountOrderType(), $order);

//         // process the form on POST
//         if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
//          $form->bind($request);
//          if ($form->isValid()) {

//              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//              $em->persist($order);
//              $em->flush();

//              return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('order', array('id' => $orderId )));
//          }
//         }

        return $this->render('AcmeAppBundle:ProducedAmount:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'order' => $order,
                'articles' => $articles,
        ));
```

I commented the request post out, because this leads only to a blank page. Now i get always this error message:

```
Method "articleOrderReferences" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in AcmeAppBundle:ProducedAmount:index.html.twig at line 150
```

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
{% for articleOrderReference in form.articleOrderReferences %}
```

Should be:

```
{% for articleOrderReference in **purchaseOrder**.articleOrderReferences %}
```

Drop the *'s of course.  I tried to make it bold.

Comment: And when I only need particular input fields (something like this: where supplier_id = $id) is there a query builder option for collections?

Comment: No.  Collections do not have any sort of query builder options.  However, you can build a custom query when you retrieve your original $order and limit supplier's there.  Different sort of question though.

Comment: I created another question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846309/query-in-multiple-embedded-collection-forms

But I need a custom query for the last FormType