# Query in multiple embedded Collection Forms

Tags: forms, symfony

In addition to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835315/multiple-embedded-collections) question. I now want to limit the input fields of my form. So that there are only input fields for the Supplier for example with the id: 2 . And not the whole collection of suppliers related to the Order. The problem is, that I have an embedded collection in an embedded collection. And i give $order to my first formtype.

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:PurchaseOrder')         
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProducedAmountOrderType(), $order);
```

My problem is, that I can't use query builder in a form type for collections. So, how can I display only the input fields for one supplier and not for everyone related to the Entity?

Comment: Maybe I don't find a solution, because I don't really need an embedded collection at the end. I need an embedded Collection, which holds some ArticleTypes, which point to another Type, that only add an Amount integer input for one field. So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this $order query:

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery("
        SELECT o, a , s
        FROM AcmeAppBundle:PurchaseOrder o
        JOIN o.purchaseOrders a
        JOIN a.articleOrderReferences s
        WHERE o.id = :orderId
          AND s.supplier = :supplierId
          AND s.amount > 0      
       ")
                   ->setParameter('orderId', $orderId)
                   ->setParameter('supplierId', $supplierId)
                   ->getOneOrNullResult();
```